# How to run phpmyadmin along with wordpress docker container using nginx-proxy?

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, phpmyadmin, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I am trying to run a [WordPress](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress) app along with [phpMyAdmin](https://hub.docker.com/r/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/) each inside of a docker container on Ubuntu VPS using [Nginx-Proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAfRP.png).

I created the following `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '3.4'
services:
    nginx-proxy:
        image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
        container_name: nginx-proxy
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
            - /etc/nginx/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d:ro
            - /etc/certificates:/etc/nginx/certs

    wordpress_app:
        image: wordpress
        restart: always
        container_name: wordpress_app
        environment:
            - VIRTUAL_HOST=wordpress.mydomain.com
            - VIRTUAL_PORT=5500
            - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=mysql_server:3306
            - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=db_username
            - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=db_password
            - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress_app
        depends_on:
            - nginx-proxy
            - mysql_server
        volumes:
            - wordpress_app_public_html:/var/www/html

    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        restart: always
        environment:
            - VIRTUAL_HOST=phpmyadmin.mydomain.com
            - VIRTUAL_PORT=5600
            - PMA_HOST=mysql_server:3306
            - MYSQL_USERNAME=root
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=db_root_password
        depends_on:
            - nginx-proxy
            - mysql_server

    mysql_server:
        image: mysql:latest
        restart: always
        container_name: mysql_server
        environment:
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress_app
            - MYSQL_USER=db_username
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=db_password
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=db_root_password
        volumes:
            - mysql_server_data:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
    wordpress_app_public_html:
    mysql_server_data:

networks:
    default:
       external:
           name: nginx-proxy
```

In the `/etc/certificates` path, I added a `.key` and `.crt` file for each of the domain..The 4 files that exists are

- phpmyadmin.mydomain.com.key
- phpmyadmin.mydomain.com.crt
- wordpress.mydomain.com.key
- wordpress.mydomain.com.crt

Now, when I execute `docker-compose up` I can browse`https://wordpress.mydomain.com` with no problems. However, when I browser `http://phpmyadmin.mydomain.com` I get the following error

> 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
> nginx/1.17.5

When I browser to `https://phpmyadmin.mydomain.com` I get a blank white page.

How can I successfully browse the php-my-admin instance?

**UPDATED**

Here is my updated `docker-compose.yml` file based on feedback below

```
version: '3.4'
services:
    nginx-proxy:
        image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
        container_name: nginx-proxy
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
            - /etc/certificates:/etc/nginx/certs

    wordpress_app:
        image: wordpress
        restart: always
        container_name: wordpress_app
        environment:
            - VIRTUAL_HOST=wordpress.mydomain.com
            - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=mysql_server:3306
            - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=db_username
            - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=db_password
            - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress_app
        depends_on:
            - nginx-proxy
            - mysql_server
        volumes:
            - wordpress_app_public_html:/var/www/html
        expose:
            - 80

    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        restart: always
        environment:
            - VIRTUAL_HOST=phpmyadmin.mydomain.com
            - PMA_HOST=mysql_server:3306
            - MYSQL_USERNAME=root
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=db_root_password
        depends_on:
            - nginx-proxy
            - mysql_server
        expose:
            - 80

    mysql_server:
        image: mysql:latest
        restart: always
        container_name: mysql_server
        environment:
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress_app
            - MYSQL_USER=db_username
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=db_password
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=db_root_password
        volumes:
            - mysql_server_data:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
    wordpress_app_public_html:
    mysql_server_data:

networks:
    default:
       external:
           name: nginx-proxy
```

Answer (score 0):

The jwilder/nginx-proxy image usually responds

> 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable nginx/1.17.5

When you can't find the service you want.
As far as I see the problem you have it in the variables `VIRTUAL_PORT` 
I am sure that both the **wordpress** image `(https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress)` and **phpmyadmin** image `(https://hub.docker.com/_/phpmyadmin)` expose port **80** and not 5500 and 5600 respectively.  Then possibly the solution to your problem is the following:

```
wordpress_app:
        image: wordpress
        restart: always
        container_name: wordpress_app
        environment:
            - VIRTUAL_HOST=wordpress.mydomain.com
            - VIRTUAL_PORT=80
            - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=mysql_server:3306
            - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=db_username
            - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=db_password
            - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress_app
        depends_on:
            - nginx-proxy
            - mysql_server
        volumes:
            - wordpress_app_public_html:/var/www/html

    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        restart: always
        environment:
            - VIRTUAL_HOST=phpmyadmin.mydomain.com
            - VIRTUAL_PORT=80
            - PMA_HOST=mysql_server:3306
            - MYSQL_USERNAME=root
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=db_root_password
        depends_on:
            - nginx-proxy
            - mysql_server
```

Comment: Thank you for our feedback. I switch into using `VIRTUAL_PORT=80` from `VIRTUAL_PORT=5500` and `VIRTUAL_PORT=5600` and per your suggestion but that did NOT work. I also removed `VIRTUAL_PORT=80` altogether and still did NOT work

Comment: I'm sorry my solution didn't work, did you already check the nginx logs and the other services to see what it says?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Where are the logs located so I can review them? If I simple run `docker-compose up` I get nothing printed on the screen when I attempt to access `https://phpmyadmin.mydomain.com` but if I got to `https://wordpress.mydomain.com` I do see logs being printed and these are good success logs. Its like the `https://phpmyadmin.mydomain.com` does not make it to the server or it isn't being routed

Comment: If I stop the `wordpress` container then the `https://wordpress.mydomain.com` shows the phpmyadmin page. This tells me that both apps are using port 80 which is causing a conflict. The question is, how can I configure each application to use a separate port?